# How can i know if the user define component is created?

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7

I create a memo inside a procedure, using this code:

```
  Global_MemoIni := TMemo.Create(Conf);
  Global_MemoIni.Parent := Conf;
  Global_MemoIni.Visible := False;
  Global_MemoIni.Align := alClient;
  Global_MemoIni.WordWrap := False;
```

When I call the procedure again it creates the global_memoini again.
How can I know if the component is created so I don't need to call it again?

Update : Can I use the `Global_MemoIni.Free` above the creation code so the next time create
the `Global_memoini` once... But i want to know if this is created...

Thank you

Comment: Looks like lazy initialization / singleton pattern, it can be extract into a helper method (GetMemoIni). But what is 'user defined'?

Answer (score 5):

You can check if Global_MemoIni is Nil and create the TMemo if it is. Otherwise it already exists, you can then free it using `Free` or `FreeAndNil`. If you use free be careful that you assign `Nil` to `Global_MemoIni`. If you don't, you can't use the `Global_MemoIni <> Nil` check.

Comment: I'd advise not to check for nil directly but to use `if Assigned(GlobalMemoIni) then`. It will be much easier to find these checks in a larger source base and has the added bonus of a "positive" test instead of a "not xxx" test.

Comment: I am not happy with the entire situation. The component should only be created once, in a defined spot, and not in a function that might be called over and over. It should not be freed manually, as the form will take care of that. If lazy instantiation is required, it can be a property that checks if it was created already (using `Assigned` indeed, Marjan) and only creates it if not. Otherwise, I would do this in the constructor or in the `FormCreate` of the form.

Comment: FWIW, if it is only abused as `TStrings` holder, a `TStringList` is indeed a lot better.

Comment: Great comments @Rudy, but don't you think they belong under the answer?

Comment: I have my reasons why i choose to use the memo componets instead of a TStringList... Thank you all of them...

Comment: @johnny: did you mean the other answer or the question?

Comment: @Rudy, to the question. Both are good points, but I think they concern the question more than any one answer.

Answer (score 3):

I honestly don't understand the point of using a memo in stead of a TStringList which is more lightweight. just do

```
unit UnitName;

interface

uses SysUtils, Windows, Classes, ...;

var Global_INI: TStringList; // <-- it's defined in the interface section, therefore
                             //     it can be accessed by any unit which uses this unit

implementation

initialization
  Global_INI := TStringList.Create;
  Global_INI.LoadFromFile( 'C:\config.ini' ); // <-- replace the file name with the
                                              //     one you want

finalization
  FreeAndNil( Global_INI );

end;
```

Comment: how did you reach the conclusion that the memo was used non-visually

Comment: Well, lot of people use controls as data structures, this assumption might correct, unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the creation state of object use:

```
if not Assigned(Global_MemoIni) then
begin
  Global_MemoIni := TMemo.Create(Conf);
  ...
end
```

And don't forget to use `FreeAndNil(Global_MemoIni)` when destroying the object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this is an arbitrary function. Either create the component in the `FormCreate` or even the constructor of the form, or make it a read-only property of the form, and use lazy instantiation, i.e.

```
if not Assigned(Global_MemoIni) then
begin
  Global_MemoIni := TMemo.Create(Self);
  // rest of your code
end;
Result := Global_MemoIni;
```

But why is it global? If you make it a field and corresponding read-only property of the form, it is easily accessible and you can protect it in the way shown above.

FWIW, instead of Free-ing the component, let the Owner (the form) do that. That way, it is available as long as the form exists, and no nasty invalid pointer issues can take place.